# ChromeCast - Not receiving call backs when remote has finished streaming Videos

Tags: android, chromecast

I have one activity where i inflate different views (instead of activities).The issue i'm facing is, I'm unable to resume play locally when i explicitly disconnect **Sender** from the **VideoCastControllerActivity**. But from within my app it gets disconnected and resumes playback.
Here is the snippet.

```
private void initializeChromecast() {

    mCastManager = CastApplication.getCastManager(CastApplicationMainActivity.this);
    mMini = (MiniController) findViewById(R.id.miniController1);
    mCastManager.addMiniController(mMini);
    mCastManager.reconnectSessionIfPossible(CastApplicationMainActivity.this, false);

    // -- Adding MiniController
    mMini = (MiniController) findViewById(R.id.miniController1);
    mCastManager.addMiniController(mMini);
    initRemoteMediaController();
    mCastConsumer = new VideoCastConsumerImpl() {

        @Override
        public void onCastDeviceDetected(final RouteInfo info) {

            /** Show tutorial if first time user and */

            boolean flag = pref.getBoolean("Eros_now_ftu", true);
            if (flag) {
                showFtu();
                editor.putBoolean("Eros_now_ftu", false);
                editor.commit();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onApplicationConnected(ApplicationMetadata appMetadata, String sessionId, boolean wasLaunched) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onApplicationConnected(appMetadata, sessionId, wasLaunched);
            isCastReceiverLaunched = wasLaunched;

        }

        @Override
        public void onApplicationDisconnected(int errorCode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onApplicationDisconnected(errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCastAvailabilityChanged(boolean castPresent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCastAvailabilityChanged(castPresent);
            isCastDevicePresent = castPresent;
            // updateActionBar(isCastDevicePresent);
        }

        public void onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated() {
            super.onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated();
            MediaStatus status = mRemoteMediaPlayer.getMediaStatus();
            int state = status.getPlayerState();
            if (state == MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_FINISHED) {
                NowPlayingView nowPlaying = NowPlayingView.getInstance(mParent);
                getDefaultParentLayout().removeAllViews();
                getDefaultParentLayout().addView(nowPlaying.getCurrentView());
                // Push data
                pushToViewStack(nowPlaying);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {

            // mMediaRouter.selectRoute(mMediaRouter.getDefaultRoute());
            /*
             * if (!mParent.getParentActivty().getActionBar().isShowing() && isCastDevicePresent) {
             * mParent.getParentActivty().getActionBar().show(); }
             */
            try {
                MediaInfo media = mCastManager.getRemoteMediaInformation();
                playMediaLocally(media);
            } catch (TransientNetworkDisconnectionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoConnectionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Implementing **RemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated()**

I'm not receiving any callbacks to **onDisconnected** and **onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated()**

```
private void initRemoteMediaController() {

    if (null == mRemoteMediaPlayer)
        mRemoteMediaPlayer = new RemoteMediaPlayer();
    mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnStatusUpdatedListener(new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnStatusUpdatedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusUpdated() {
            MediaStatus status = mRemoteMediaPlayer.getMediaStatus();
            int state = status.getPlayerState();
            if (state == MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_FINISHED) {
                NowPlayingView nowPlaying = NowPlayingView.getInstance(mParent);
                getDefaultParentLayout().removeAllViews();
                getDefaultParentLayout().addView(nowPlaying.getCurrentView());
                // Push data
                pushToViewStack(nowPlaying);

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Other MediaRouter Setup

```
public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume() was called");
    mCastManager = CastApplication.getCastManager(this);
    if (null != mCastManager) {
        mCastManager.addVideoCastConsumer(mCastConsumer);
        mCastManager.incrementUiCounter();
    }

    super.onResume();
```

}

```
public void onPause() {
    mCastManager.decrementUiCounter();
    mCastManager.removeVideoCastConsumer(mCastConsumer);
    super.onPause();

    /*
     * if(mImageFetcher != null){ mImageFetcher.setExitTasksEarly(true); mImageFetcher.flushCache(); }
     */
}
```

Comment: You need to provide information on how you are registering your VideoCastManager instance, how you are starting discovery and stop that, etc. Are you calling incrementUiCounter()? If so, where?

Comment: Initializing VideoCastManager instance in the mainActivities onCreate(); and incrementUiCounter in OnResume

Comment: In the post, you mention you are unable to resume local playback when you disconnect there. What does that mean exactly? The CastVideos-android app does all of these things, so have you compared your app with that to see where the two are different?

Comment: The following scenario will explain the issue.  1) Successfully casting initiated the app redirects to VideoCastControllerActivity Disconnect mediaRouter explicitly-- here i dont receive callBacks to **onDisconnect()**--fails  2) Casting in progress VideoCastControllerActivity is pushed to view on backpress resumes to previous view of the app showing miniConroller --- Explicit disconnection here receives callBack to onDisconnect() and works fine

Comment: I have compared and followed the same and setUp VideoCastManager simillarally...So im unable to understand where i going wrong

Comment: You said your app is made of a single activity. What do you do when you leave your main activity (say, in onPause())? When you disconnect while the VideoCastController is visible, what happens? Does that activity close? What does your sender log shows? If the callbacks are unregistered in your main activity, when you disconnect in the VideoCastControllerActivity, your activity is not going to receive the callbacks if it hasn't yet had a chance to re-register the callbacks. Try adding callbacks to your applications to verify (or do not unregister callbacks in your activity upon leaving).

Comment: Thanks Mr Naddaf.. It worked.... So as you said i stop unregistering callbacks in the mainActivity....

Comment: Make sure you do unregister them when your app is going away, for example in onPause but wrap that inside a conditional on isFinishing() or so.

Comment: Sure Mr.Ali, Thanks,Im unable to receive MediaStatus its returning null--- onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated()

Comment: Make sure you are calling RemoteMediaPlayer.requestStatus(..) when you receive a call back on successful launch of app.

Comment: As updated code above i have not initialized googleApiClient or Cast.CastOptions apiOptionsBuilder because the **mRemoteMediaPlayer.requestStatus(apiClient);** requires apiClient